# How can I remove press animation of RaisedButton in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

Hi I want to remove the Animation that occurs when 'RaisedButton' is pressed in Flutter.

How can I do it?

[image]

```
RaisedButton(
                splashColor: Colors.transparent,
                highlightColor: Colors.transparent,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(0),
                color: Colors.white,
                elevation: 0,
                onPressed: (){
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,  // 기본 파라미터, SecondRoute로 전달
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>TotalNotification()) // SecondRoute를 생성하여 적재
                  );
                },
                child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/images/BellButton.svg',
                  width: screenWidth * 0.0777777777777778,
                  height: screenWidth * 0.0777777777777778,
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: have you tried using an IconButton instead of a RaisedButton?

Comment: I solved this issue using gesture detector but I'll try this too thx :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could give you an idea. 
Just wrap it with `Container` instead of `RaisedButton` and seek the help of `GesureDetector`

```
GestureDetector(
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push( context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>TotalNotification()));
          },
          child: Container(
            height: 50.0,
            width: 50.0,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: SvgPicture.asset(
                  'assets/images/BellButton.svg',
                  width: screenWidth * 0.0777777777777778,
                  height: screenWidth * 0.0777777777777778,
            ),
       ),
   ),
```

Hope that suits your case!

Comment: Thanks a lot!!!!!! It works perfect for me!! Have a nice day!!